# Is PCA a non-linear transform?

Tags: pca, python, dimensionality-reduction, linear, nonlinear

In the article [Relative Information Loss in the PCA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0429), the authors make, at some point (in the introductory section), the following statement:

> In case the orthogonal matrix is not known a priori, but has to be estimated from a set of input data vectors collected in the matrix $\underline{X}$, the PCA becomes a **nonlinear** operation:
>
> $$\underline{Y} = \underline{w}(\underline{X})\underline{X}$$
>
> Here, $\underline{w}$ is a matrix-valued function which computes the orthogonal matrix required for rotating the data (e.g., using the QR algorithm).

This statement contrasts with most statements about PCA, which is regarded as a **linear transformation**.

I designed a toy experiment to check the linearity (additivity property):  $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$.

```
import numpy
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numpy.random.seed(42)
    m = 100
    d = 3
    X = numpy.random.normal(size = (m, d))

    # Center data
    X -= numpy.mean(X, axis = 0)

    pca = PCA(n_components = d)
    pca.fit(X)
    Y = pca.transform(X)

    # Check linearity, pca(a + b) = pca(a) + pca(b)
    for i in range(0, m):
        for j in range(0, m):
            d = pca.transform([X[i] + X[j]]) - (Y[i] + Y[j])
            assert numpy.allclose(d, numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]))
```

The expression $f(a + b) - (f(a) + f(b))$, where $f = \mathrm{PCA}$, seems to be the **zero vector**, thus I assume the transform (PCA) is linear.

What am I missing then, that PCA is considered non-linear when the orthogonal matrix (the matrix of the principal components) is estimated from $X$ (see the quote above)?

Comment: Does this have something to do with how sklearn centers the data before transforming it?

Comment: The only case where $w$ has a formula linear in $X$ is in one dimension.  If you think otherwise, it may be due to a misunderstanding about what $w$ represents: what do you think it is?

Comment: @Aaron and amoeba, thank you for your comments. I have updated the sample code. $X$ is now centered before PCA.

Comment: @whuber, in the referenced article, $w$ represents _"a matrix-valued function which computes the orthogonal matrix required for rotating the data"._ Thus, in my understanding, $w$ is the operation that performs the SVD on the covariance matrix, then returns the (transposed) matrix of eigenvectors.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that such a function cannot be linear?  In fact, how could you even make sense of adding and rescaling a set of eigenvectors (given that each eigenvector must have unit length)?

Comment: @whuber, thank you! It took me a while to understand your thoughts. Please correct me if I'm wrong: $w(\cdot)$ is a set of eigenvectors, thus the addition $w(\cdot) + w(\cdot)$ and the multiplication with a scalar $\alpha w(\cdot)$ do not make any sense. Therefore, $w$ can't be a linear transform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the confusion is due to *what* exactly is meant here to be linear or non-linear.

Using the notation of your quote, operation $w(X)$ maps a data matrix $X$ into a projector $P_k$ on the first $k$ principal axes of $X$. Let us be completely clear about the notation here; for simplicity let us fix $k=1$ and assume that $X$ is centered. Then $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ and $P\in \mathbb P^p \subset \mathbb R^{p\times p}$, where by $\mathbb P^p$ I mean the space of all matrices of the form $P=\mathbf{uu}^\top$ with $\mathbf u\in \mathbb R^p$ and $\|\mathbf u\|=1$.

Now:

- Operation $w:\mathbb R^{n\times p} \to \mathbb P^p$ is non-linear.
- Operation $P:\mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R$ is linear.

The quote talks about the $w(\cdot)$ function; it transforms a data matrix into a projection operator. It is non-linear. Your script investigates the $P(\cdot)$ function; it transforms a high-dimensional vector into a low-dimensional PCA projection, *given a fixed dataset*. It is linear.

**So $w(\cdot)$ is a non-linear mapping into linear projections.**

No contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! Still, I am not sure why there is the constraint $P=\mathbf{uu}^\top$. A matrix of that form is symmetric, right? However, as far as I know, the projection matrix learned by PCA (the matrix comprising the eigenvectors) is not necessarily a symmetric one.